# Taxonomy links not case sensitive

Tags: go, hugo

I have this taxonomy structure:

http://localhost:1313/blog/destination/germany/

http://localhost:1313/blog/destination/japan/

http://localhost:1313/blog/destination/uk/

The link text for each link shows: Germany, Japan but UK shows up as Uk and not UK in the `title` tag, I have set the taxonomy to UK but it doesn’t output it as I wanted. I want to keep the URL’s lowercase but the link text to be the same as my front matter. My site’s title also shows Uk

**Front matter:**

```
destination: "UK"
```

**Taxonomy links:**

```
{{ with .Params.destination }}<a href="/blog/destination{{ . | urlize | relLangURL }}">{{ . }}</a>{{ end }}
```

**Title tag:**

```
<title>{{ .Site.Title }} - {{ .Title }}</title>
```

I tried to look at the `config.toml` documentation but wasn’t able to find what I was looking for.

Answer (score 0):

Adding: `preserveTaxonomyNames = true` fixes the problem
https://discourse.gohugo.io/t/taxonomy-text-links-same-as-my-front-matter/13252/3?u=noodles